# How to change bootstrap active tab on window onload function

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

After the page is loaded completely i want to change the active tab to tab. My html is:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab1">Video</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab2">Maps</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab3">Gallery</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="tab1" class="tab-pane fade">....</div>
<div id="tab2" class="tab-pane fade in active map">....</div>
<div id="tab3" class="tab-pane fade gallery">....</div>
```

and the jquery i'm trying is:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('.nav-tabs a[href="#tab1"]').tab('show');
});
```

But that doesn't work. How can i do it? Thanks in advance.

NOTE: I can't remove the active class from 2nd tab as it's compulsory for my code to be active while page is loaded

Comment: try: $('.nav-tabs ul a:first').tab('show');

Comment: Sorry, not working .

Comment: this may help: http://jsfiddle.net/xFW8t/12/

Comment: which tab do you want to highlight?

Comment: @MohitBhardwaj #tab1

Comment: There seems to be no `#tab1` tab in your code. You should instead use #daily, #map and #gallery

Comment: @MohitBhardwaj Edited the question. Please check it.

Comment: You have this in your `href` but where is the div with id `tab1`? The `href` values should correspond to the id's of the div's that need to be shown/hidden.

Comment: @MohitBhardwaj Yaa i know. i forgot to change the id while copy pasting. I am using the same id in href and div's id in my code .

Comment: You cannot remove the active class from the li, I mean from here `<li class="active">` ?

Comment: @MohitBhardwaj Yes I can. but after page is loaded i need to make this li active again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @MohitBhardwaj, but Sorry that didn't worked. Finally i tried this

```
 $(window).load(function() {
        // $("a[data-toggle=tab][href=#daily]").tab("show");
        $(".tab-content #map").removeClass('active');
        $(".tab-content #daily").addClass('in active');
    });
```

And this worked. Well i don't know if this is the right way or not but by this i achieved what i wanted.

Answer (score 1):

If you just remove the `active` class from the first `li`, the second tab is automatically highlighted after page load. Please let me know if I am missing something.

```js
$("a[data-toggle=tab][href=#daily]").tab("show");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#daily">Daily</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#map">Maps</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#gallery">Gallery</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="daily" class="tab-pane fade">Daily Tab</div>
<div id="map" class="tab-pane fade in active map">Map Tab</div>
<div id="gallery" class="tab-pane fade gallery">Gallery Tab</div>




<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

*Edited the answer*
Please check now if it works for you. I think you already have posted the code that I have added but not sure why it does not work for you. Please check this solution once.

Comment: I'm sorry if i could not make you understand what the question is. After the  page is loaded i want id="daily" active.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
 var hash = window.location.hash;
 var sTabHash = hash.split('#tab');
 var isTab = sTabHash[1] > 0 ? sTabHash[1] : 0;
            if(isTab > 0){
                $(".nav.nav-tabs li").removeClass("active");
                $(".tab-content div[class*=tab-pane]").removeClass("active");
                $(".nav.nav-tabs li a[href*=tab"+isTab+"]").parent().addClass("active");
                $("#tab"+isTab).addClass("active");
            }
            else{
                $(".nav.nav-tabs li a[href*=tab1]").parent().addClass("active");
                $("#tab1").addClass("active");
            }
```